# Javascript doesnt update style

Tags: javascript, html, css

Why doesn't this work?
`localStorage.fontSize` contains the proper value, but the first `document.body.style.fontSize = localStorage.fontSize + "pt";` doesn't update the style.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

if(!localStorage.fontSize){
    localStorage.fontSize = Number(11); 
}
else{
    document.body.style.fontSize = localStorage.fontSize + "pt"; /* This row doesnt run */
}

function resetFont(){
    localStorage.fontSize = Number(11);
    document.body.style.fontSize = "11pt";
}
function enlargeFont(){
    localStorage.fontSize++;
    document.body.style.fontSize = localStorage.fontSize + "pt"; /* But this does if called */
}

</script>
```

No jQuery snippets please.

Comment: Seems like `document.body` does not exist at the moment the code is run. Move the code to the end of the `body` tag. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959/218196, it's basically the same.

Comment: Try placing your script tag just before the end of the body tag

Comment: Did you look at the console? Open it up!

Comment: Thank you Felix, case closed!

Comment: Shouldn't this code be at the *beginning* of the `<body>` tag instead of the end? If it's at the end you could have a flash of unstyled content where the font size changes after the page has been displayed.

Comment: @FelixKling, please create an answer for your answer, so that user1677709 can mark that as the correct answer. That way, no one wastes their time on answering a question that has already been answered.

Comment: @myfunkyside: This question is two years old, but ok.

Comment: @FelixKling - Ha, didn't even notice that:D But it does illustrate my point: I was just browsing on the main page for unanswered questions, and this one appeared in that list, because officially it still didn't have an answer

Comment: @myfunkyside: Point taken! Though I'm not very hopeful that the answer will get accepted...

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `document.body` does not exist at the moment the code is run. Move the code to the beginning or the end of the `body` tag.

See [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959/218196), it's basically the same.